# Use regex to get comment block from a git log

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm stuck on something that might be very simple, but I can't find a solution. I'm using Python since few days and I need to use regex to get part of a file.

I put the result of a `git log -p` into a file, and now I want to extract some informations. The only thing I can't extract is the comment block.

This block is between : a date line AND (a diff line OR the end of the list).

```
...
Date:   Wed Jul 3 22:32:36 2013 +0200

    Here is the comment
    of a commit

    and I have to
    extract it

diff --git a/dir.c b/dir.c
...
```

---

```
...
Date:   Wed Jul 3 22:32:36 2013 +0200

    Here is the comment
    of a commit

    and I have to
    extract it
```

So I tried to do this :

```
commentBlock = re.compile("(?<=Date:.{32}\n\n).+(?=|\n\ndiff)", re.M|re.DOTALL)
findCommentBlock = re.findall(commentBlock,commitBlock[i]) # I've splited my git log everytime I find a "commit" line.
```

Problems are :

- the length of the date line can change. It can be `Date:.{32}` if the date is between the 1st to 9th or `Date:.{33}` if the date is 2 numbers long.
- I don't know how to say : "the comment block stops when a line starts by `diff` OR when it's the end of the list (or the file)".

P.S. I'm working on Python 3.x and I almost finished my script so I don't really wanna use a specific tool like `GitPython` (that only works on 2.x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
rgx = re.compile(r'^Date: .+?\n+(.+?)(?:^diff |\Z)', re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
comments = rgx.findall(txt)
```

A few notes:

- I don't think you need to worry about the length of the Date line.
- Capture the part you care about. This has two implications. (1) To ignore the Date line, just consume (non-greedily) everything through the first newlines. (2) You don't need a lookahead assertion; a non-capturing group `(?:...)` will work fine.
- It's probably a good idea to make the captured wildcard non-greedy as well: `.+?`.
- You can indicate the end of a string in a regex with `\Z`. Thus, the non-capturing group means: (a) a line beginning with "diff " or (b) end of string.
- More details on regex features can be found in the excellent [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Comment: It works perfectly for the end. How can change your code to extract only the comment block ? I don't want to get the date line.
Thanks for your notes ! :D

Comment: Great, thanks ! I stil have a problme though.
I've this : `('Date:   Wed Jul 3 22:32:36 2013 +0200\n\n    my comment block', ' my comment block ')`. How can I just get the second part ? (dunno if I'm clear)

Comment: indeed, my bad ! Thank you very much FMc :D

Answer (score 0):

Though the date may change in length, it is definitely terminated by a new-line, so why limit the number of characters at all?

Anyway, you should be able to do something like `{32,33}` to capture the range.

Comment: you're right about the length. With FMc solution, it doesn't work when I write `^Date:.{32,33}\n\n.+?(?=^diff |\Z)`

Sorry, I'm still very confused with regex

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
re.findall('Date:.+?\n\s*(.+?)\s*(?:diff|$)', text, re.S)
```

This should return a list of comment entries, assuming that all of the log entries follow the same pattern you have laid out here.